# MySQL IF statement procedure creation error

Tags: mysql

why won't this run? Complains of error when I try to create the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `xxx_testIF`
(
  IN _memberId int
)
BEGIN
IF _memberId = 0
    select * from incident_report
ELSE
    select * from incident_report where filed_by = _memberId
END IF;
END
```

Comment: It would be easier to address the issue if you share what the error says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use Delimiters while creating procedures and also you have missing `THEN` after the `IF` condition.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `xxx_testIF`
(
  IN _memberId int
)
BEGIN
    IF _memberId = 0 THEN
        select * from incident_report;
    ELSE
        select * from incident_report where filed_by = _memberId;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now!